# Query SQLite through third-party "proxy" with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am attempting to query (manipulation optional) a SQLite database using Laravel Eloquent. A driver already exists for this an is delightfully easy to use.

However, the database is remote and part of a video game. The game supports RCON which allows me to send commands and in this case, I can send SQL statements.

My current state:

1. Send a SQL statement prefixed with "sql" to remote machine via third party library:

```
sql SELECT id, level, guild, isAlive FROM characters
```

2. Receive a line delimited string, prefixed by record number:

```
     id |  level |  guild |  isAlive |
#0 1183 |     14 |     60 |        1 |
#1  636 |     10 |     60 |        1 |
#2   41 |     30 |     60 |        1 |
#3   47 |     27 |     60 |        1 |
#4   49 |     38 |     60 |        1 |
#5  403 |     32 |     60 |        1 |
#6   50 |     31 |     60 |        1 |
#7 1389 |     44 |     60 |        1 |
```

3. Parse the output line by line in a particularly unsavory method and manually assign them to a custom built model/class.

I would really like to incorporate Eloquent in *any* capacity rather than use my own custom classes. As I typed this post out, I realized I don't believe I'll be able to "piggy back" off of the existing SQLite driver and this would likely be a completely new driver altogether.

However, to those more experienced than myself, do you have any suggestions or methods of approaching this situation?

Comment: So, basically your problem is that you cannot normally connect to this database?

Comment: Correct. The database "server" is the game itself. The underlying SQLite instance is not directly accessible to me without transferring the database to the machine Laravel is running on which isn't viable in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up processing the output of the RCON command. The downside is that it is particularly static. I have to build around things like the columns being selected with the SQL statement and adjusting the results to proper types.

I am using https://github.com/gorcon/rcon-cli and wrapped a query class around it:

```
class RconDatabase
{
    const RCON_EXECUTABLE = __DIR__ . '/../bin/rcon';

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        if (!is_executable(self::RCON_EXECUTABLE)) throw new FilePermissionException('Unable to execute RCON');

        $cmd = self::RCON_EXECUTABLE.' -a '.Config::get('rcon.host').':'.Config::get('rcon.port').' -p '.Config::get('rcon.password').' -c "sql '. $sql .'"';
        $output = shell_exec($cmd);

        if ($output == null) throw new RconConnectionException('No response from RCON server');
        if (strpos($output, 'authentication failed') !== false) throw new RconAuthenticationException();
        if (strpos($output, 'dial tcp') !== false) throw new RconNetworkException();

        $lines = preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $output);

        $results = array();
        $last_column = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
            if (empty($lines[$i])) continue;

            $columns = str_getcsv($lines[$i], '|');

            for ($x = 0; $x < count($columns); $x++) {
                if ($i == 0 && empty($columns[$x])) {
                    $last_column = $x;
                    continue;
                }

                if ($x == 0 && preg_match('/^#[0-9]+\s+(\S+)/', $columns[0], $match))
                    $columns[$x] = $match[1];

                $columns[$x] = trim($columns[$x]);
            }

            if ($i == 0) continue;

            if ($last_column > 0) unset($columns[$last_column]);

            array_push($results, $columns);
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```